# chef template gives No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen Errno::ENOENT

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have chef recipe with this block  :

```
if ( platform === 'suse' )
        repo_name="some_repo"
        template '/etc/zypp/repos.d/some_repo' do
           source 'some_repo.rpm.repo.erb'
           variables( :os => "#{os}", :distro => "#{distro}", :repo_name => "#{repo_name}" )
           owner "root"
           group "root"
           mode '644'
        end
end
```

I understand the template should by default create the file.
But it doesn't create the file and it gives the error `No such file or directory`.

The template `some_repo.rpm.repo.erb` itself looks like this:

```
[<%= @repo_name %>] 
name=<%= @repo_name %>
baseurl=http://BLA.com//repos/<%= @os %>/<%= @distro %>
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
sslverify=0
proxy=_none_
```

What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT :full error logs

```
Recipe Compile Error in /tmp/ldt_chef_run/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================

Errno::ENOENT
-------------
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /etc/zypp/repos.d/some_repo

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /tmp/ldt_chef_run/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/recipes/default.rb:106:in `read'
  /tmp/ldt_chef_run/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/recipes/default.rb:106:in `block in from_file'
  /tmp/ldt_chef_run/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/recipes/default.rb:104:in `from_file'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/tmp/ldt_chef_run/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/zabbix_agent/recipes/default.rb:

 99:      owner 'root'
100:      group 'root'
101:      mode '0755'
102:      action :create
103:    end
104:    file '/tmp/some.repos.d/some.repo' do
105:      mode '0644'
106>>     content IO.read(node['somepackage'][node['platform']]['repo_source'])
107:      action :create
108:    end
109:  end
110:
111:  ######### Install package ###########
112:  #package 'somepackage' do
113:  #   action :install
114:  #end
115:  node['somepackage'][node['platform']]['packages'].each do |pkg|

System Info:
------------
chef_version=14.2.0
platform=redhat
platform_version=7.5
ruby=ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
program_name=/bin/chef-solo
executable=/opt/chef/bin/chef-solo


Running handlers:
[2019-02-10T11:32:27+02:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2019-02-10T11:32:27+02:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2019-02-10T11:32:27+02:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2019-02-10T11:32:27+02:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 11 seconds
[2019-02-10T11:32:27+02:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/ldt_chef_run/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2019-02-10T11:32:27+02:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/ldt_chef_run/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2019-02-10T11:32:27+02:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2019-02-10T11:32:27+02:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2019-02-10T11:32:27+02:00] FATAL: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /etc/zypp/repos.d/some_repo
[2019-02-10T11:32:27+02:00] FATAL: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /etc/zypp/repos.d/some_repo
```

EDIT2 :
I know the issue is related to a block coming **after** the
template i have this :

```
if %w(redhat suse sles).include?(node['platform'])
  directory '/tmp/some.repos.d' do
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '0755'
    action :create
  end

  file '/tmp/some.repos.d/some.repo' do
    mode '0644'
    content IO.read(node['somepakage'][node['platform']]['repo_source'])
    action :create
  end
end
```

I wanted to copy the content of the file that the template created:
"/etc/zypp/repos.d/some_repo" 
to /tmp/some.repos.d/some.repo

it seems like this block is creating the error with the template block 
which make the template not creating the new file, as a resulted the
content IO.read block gets an error as the file was not created at the template stage.

this error only happed if i delete the file :
/etc/zypp/repos.d/some_repo 
for testing to see if cookbook will re-create it.
if this file exists no errors.

So, why "content IO.read" cancels "template" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the workaround :

Addings this line to the start of all blockes :

```
if %w(redhat suse sles ubuntu debian).include?(node['platform'])

  directory '/tmp/some.repos.d' do
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '0755'
    action :create
  end
end
```

Then just duplicate the "template" block , for the other file :

```
if ( platform === 'suse' )
        repo_name="some_repo"
        template '/etc/zypp/repos.d/some.repo' do
           source 'some.rpm.repo.erb'
           variables( :os => "#{os}", :distro => "#{distro}", :repo_name => "#{repo_name}" )
           owner "root"
           group "root"
           mode '644'
        end

    template '/tmp/some.repos.d/some.repo' do
        source 'some.rpm.repo.erb'
            variables( :os => "#{os}", :distro => "#{distro}", :repo_name => "#{repo_name}" )
            owner "root"
            group "root"
            mode '644'
        end

end
```